# Getting htaccess to work in CodeIgniter on Mac

Tags: php, macos, .htaccess, codeigniter, osx-yosemite

I'm using web sharing on my Mac running Yosemite. The configuration of my `user.conf` is:

```
<Directory "/Users/someuser/Sites/"> 
       AddLanguage en .en 
       LanguagePriority en 
       ForceLanguagePriority Fallback 
       Options FollowSymLinks Indexes MultiViews 
       AllowOverride All 
       Order allow,deny 
       Allow from localhost 
       Require all granted 
 </Directory>
```

For a project kept at `/Sites/myproject/`, I'm not able to get the `.htaccess` working. I have to append `index.php` in the URL which I don't want.

Comment: I have same issue, one trick work with me just use php dev server to serve the app it will run. cd into your project root and `php -S localhost:8888` and see

Comment: @Saqueib: Still not working for me.

Comment: run `php --ini` in terminal and edit loaded file, search for `mod_rewrite` and un-comment the module (remove # from start) and `restart apache`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one works on mac for me.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```